# Kafka consumer group do not list newly added topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka 0.10. 4 topics are present in my kafka consumer group name `consumer-group`. I am adding new topic to the same `consumer-group`.

When I execute the command

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list localhost:9092 --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

all my old 4 topics gets listed.

But my newly added topic is not getting list down. Further Kafka Consumer not processing any messages from the 5th topic.

when tried `kafka-consumer-console.sh`, able to see the messages in console. But not received via the consumer-group

How to resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am adding new topic to the same consumer-group" ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  I meant adding a consumer for a new topic under the existing consumer-group. hope i am clear.